# How can unused tracks be removed from the NLA?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

With autokeying enabled I accidentally moved a few objects, unfortunately they now appear in the *NLA editor*. I removed the actions saved and reload but I can't get rid of the entries.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior has been changed after 2.66a. Just tried to discuss with the designer. As explained, it is one of the main ways to prepare some places to add NLA strips from pre-made actions, and got its advantages, too.

To make them invisible, click the third toggle on the header to exclude them from displaying.

[image]

Comment: This solves the problems with objects. To remove the ones with Compositing Nodetree, I had to delete (in Python console) the Nodetree Actions. I don't know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: @MarioMey Can you provide an example? Just wonder why the compositing tree data relates to the problem here.

Comment: When we create a node group and animate something inside it, a new Action is created and appear in NLA as an Action (not yet track). When we ungroup the group... or clear keyframes, most of times, it disappears, sometimes, **it doesn't**. And here is where we would need to delete the empty Action. You can do it with Blender console, like this: `bpy.data.actions['CompositingNodetreeAction.001'].clear_user()`. Maybe you want to delete it, but I prefer to reopen the file. See this [screenshot] (http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=108866) before deleting the Actions.

Comment: Be careful when using `D.actions['CompNodetreeAction'].user_clear()` and removing the Action like `D.actions.remove(D.actions['CompNodetreeAction']`... **you can make Blender crash** (it just happened to me). It's better only to clear users and see what happens. Maybe you are using that Action somewhere else.